# Jquery $.Ajax() keep getting 401 response

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-status-code-401

I'm trying to get JSON through an API but it keeps giving me

> Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

This is my code

```
        $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function (request)
        {
            request.withCredentials = true;
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic" +  btoa("usernamehere:keyhere"));
        },
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: url,
```

With the username and key different ofcourse.
I've tried without btoa, i've tried using `headers:` and I've edited the CORS.
But nothing works, it just keeps throwing the same error over and over eventhough I can login with the credentials if I go to the url.

Comment: Have you checked the APIs documentation. What form of authentication does it support?

Comment: does the resource support `OPTIONS` via `CORS`?

Comment: @Liam It uses Basic Auth

Answer (score 0):

```
contentType: 'application/json'
```

Was not allowed, that fixed it.